# UWP app wireless connection crashes app without exception

Tags: raspberry-pi, uwp, wifi, windows-10-iot-core

Im trying to connect to wireless network from my uwp application (windows iot core os)

I can scan and list all wireless networks around me without any problem.
When i try to connect without credential connection fails as expected and program continues.
My problem is when i try to connect to a network with **credentials** my app closes and i cannot catch it even with using try catch.App goes from screen ( rasberry pi 3 ) and debug session is lost.Instead it should return me connection failed invalid credentials.

I'm also testing Microsoft samples for connecting wireless and i observed this behave happens in Microsoft sample when you try to connect to a network that you already connected it crashes without any exception
 https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/WiFiConnector/CS

To Summurize; With following code if call firstAdapter.ConnectAsync() without credentials its normal but if call it with credentials program goes off from screen even without exception.
**Note:** i call await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync(); before i start.

my code as following

```
var adapterResult = await WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync();
            if (adapterResult.Count >= 1)
            {
                WiFiAdapter firstAdapter = adapterResult[0];
                await firstAdapter.ScanAsync();
                var network = firstAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks.FirstOrDefault();
                PasswordCredential credential = new PasswordCredential();
                credential.Password = "zp1PDQPdYFpCU";
                try
                {
                    WiFiConnectionResult result;
                    if (network.SecuritySettings.NetworkAuthenticationType == Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkAuthenticationType.Open80211 &&
                            network.SecuritySettings.NetworkEncryptionType == NetworkEncryptionType.None)
                    {
                        result = await firstAdapter.ConnectAsync(network, WiFiReconnectionKind.Automatic);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = await firstAdapter.ConnectAsync(network, WiFiReconnectionKind.Automatic, credential);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
```

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in the app.xaml.cs files unhandled exception do you get an error?

Comment: I will try now and let you know by the way what strange is if i use password less than 8 characters program doesn't crash.it returns result as invalid credentials. but if i type credential password longer than 7 chars it crashes

Comment: What's your windows iot core os version?

Comment: Sorry for late answer.I was debugging on wireless network.I noticed that this happens when debbuging on wirless network.I connected with a cable i uploaded my program into windows iot core device and it runs now.i can connect to any wireless. I guess program was not giving exception or even if it was giving i could not catch because my connection was interrupting.I still don't know why it interrupts while debugging on wireless even when connection to new wireless network fails.